# remove_action returns FALSE

Tags: actions

I'm trying to remove the canonical link reference from my page headers and I'm using the following code in my `functions.php`:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'rel_canonical');
```

However, when I test the return value of remove_action it's value is `FALSE` and I notice that the canonical link reference is still rendered in the `head` of my pages.

I've tried wrapping the `remove_action` in an `init` but I get the same result:

```
function my_init()
{
   remove_action('wp_head', 'rel_canonical');
}

add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

How do I remove the canonical link reference from my page headers?

Comment: Where is this action being set?

Comment: You mean by Wordpress? In wp-includes/default-filters.php line 209

Comment: Works for me - are you using any plugins?

Comment: Which one is working for you? With or without the init?

Answer (score 2):

Locate the original `add_action` call and make sure that your `remove_action` call exactly mimics it including the `$priority` and `$accepted_args` parameters.

Comment: Already checked that. It's added in wp-includes/default-filters.php line 209. No priorities or other parameters are specified.